# Navigation bar scroll to active li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul with id mainul in navigation bar. When page reload, the navigation bar is set to start.But, I want to set or scroll to the active li.

My html code is,

```
<ul id="mainul">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
.
.
.
.
.
<li>25</li>
<li class="active">26</li>
<li>27</li>
</ul>
```

My javascript code is,

```
var rowpos = $('.active').position();
$('#mainul').scrollTop(rowpos.top);
```

But it's not working

Please help me.

Comment: pls give information which will help others to understand and answer you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you can use this function:

```
function scrollToElement(ele) {
    $(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
}
```

Like this:

```
scrollToElement($('li.active'));
```

Keep in mind that it will be good to call it when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    scrollToElement($('li.active'));
});
```